# PrivacyScreen Plugin Cordova - for TouchID Disable

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing app on ionic, I used `PrivacyScreen` Plugin to view splash screen on multitasking. But the splash screen also shown in `TouchID` popup, I want to disable this splash screen for particular screen or `TouchID` popup.

Any Idea ?

Comment: Were u able to solve this issue? I have the same problem

Comment: https://github.com/devgeeks/PrivacyScreenPlugin/issues/33

still OPEN bug